# How to mock class constructor and static function with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I want to mock simultaneously both my default exported class constructor and a static function of the said class that instantiate and returns an instance of the said class(singleton). How can I do it with Jest. Here is a code sample:

```
export default class MyClass {
    private static instance: MyClass;
    private data: any;
    
    constructor() {
        this.data = ...DefaultData...;
    }

    public static getInstance(): MyClass {
        if (!MyClass.instance) {
            MyClass.instance = new MyClass();
        }

        return MyClass.instance;
    }

    public setData(newData){
        this.data = newData;
    }

    public methodA(){...doSomethingWith_this.data}
}
```

Also as requested heres an example of my test where I only have mocked the 'getInstance' method.

```
import MyClass from 'path/to/MyClass';

jest.mock('path/to/MyClass', () => {
    const instance = {
        methodA: jest.fn(),
        setData: jest.fn()
    };
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        default: {
            getInstance: () => instance
        }
    };
});

describe('SystemUnderTest', () => {
    it('test for in code instantiation', ()=>{});

    it('test for singleton instance', ()=>{});
})
```

Finally the error I get when running the tests is this

> _MyClass.default is not a constructor

Comment: `MyClass` represents the wrong implementation of the Singleton pattern, that becomes an anti-pattern when it's implemented this way, exactly because of the problem you have. The idea of _"there must always be one and only one instance of this class throughout the entire application"_, most of the times proves to be wrong. Decouple the `MyClass` class from the component that guards the unique instance. You can even make using that component to create/get that unique instance easier than instantiating it to make it more appealing in the production code...

Comment: ... However, you need to be able to create multiple instances of `MyClass` in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Change `this` to `MyClass`. A static variable is a class property that is used in a class and not on the instance of the class.

```
export default class MyClass {
    private static instance: MyClass;
    
    constructor() {}

    public static getInstance(): MyClass {
        if (!MyClass.instance) {
            MyClass.instance = new MyClass();
        }

        return MyClass.instance;
    }
}
```

This is how a singleton works based on your code example.